# Jakarta verify class not found Entity Annotation

Tags: maven, jpa, glassfish

I have simple class that show you in the below and Problem is sometimes GlassFish log show error and webapp not working in right way , after restart the glassfish server the problem diappears and I don't know why! I think maybe Jakarta and Javax package or glassfish not match in right way !
The class(bean) is :

```
package ir.mehritco.megnatis.components.users;

import ir.mehritco.megnatis.beans.StorageInformation;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name = "users")
@Table(name = "table_users")
@Entity
public class User extends StorageInformation {

    @Column(name = "login_id", unique = true)
    String username;
    @Column
    String name, password, tel;
    long parentId;
    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    Scope scope = Scope.NONE;
    @Column
    String domain;

    @Column(name = "status_access")
    Integer status;


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public long getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(long parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public Scope getScope() {
        return scope;
    }

    public void setScope(Scope scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }
}
```

and Log of glassfish :

```
[2023-05-08T03:37:37.471089+03:30] [GF 7.0.3] [INFO] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [levelValue: 800] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2023-05-08T03:37:37.474092+03:30] [GF 7.0.3] [INFO] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [levelValue: 800] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.ProcessAllAnnotatedTypes.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<?>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2023-05-08T03:37:37.482099+03:30] [GF 7.0.3] [INFO] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [levelValue: 800] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2023-05-08T03:37:38.235327+03:30] [GF 7.0.3] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.soteria.servlet.SamRegistrationInstaller] [tid: _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Initializing Soteria 3.0.2 for context '/Sito-1.0']]

[2023-05-08T03:37:38.662241+03:30] [GF 7.0.3] [INFO] [faces.config.listener.version] [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.config] [tid: _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Initializing Mojarra 4.0.2 for context '/Sito-1.0']]

[2023-05-08T03:37:38.996564+03:30] [GF 7.0.3] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [jakarta.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [Sito-1.0] at [/Sito-1.0]]]

[2023-05-08T03:37:39.009576+03:30] [GF 7.0.3] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Sito-1.0 was successfully deployed in 8,262 milliseconds.]]

[2023-05-08T03:37:43.939419+03:30] [GF 7.0.3] [INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.logging.stdout] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [levelValue: 800] [[
  We get you : 1]]

[2023-05-08T03:37:43.942421+03:30] [GF 7.0.3] [WARNING] [] [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.lifecycle] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [levelValue: 900] [[
  //D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/Templates/Components/Management/Users/UserSelection.xhtml @25,19 listener="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Entity bean class: class ir.mehritco.megnatis.components.users.User, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.
jakarta.el.ELException: //D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/Templates/Components/Management/Users/UserSelection.xhtml @25,19 listener="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Entity bean class: class ir.mehritco.megnatis.components.users.User, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.faces.core.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxHandler.java:391)
    at jakarta.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:99)
    at jakarta.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:79)
    at jakarta.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:471)
    at jakarta.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:858)
    at jakarta.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1332)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:56)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:72)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:159)
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:691)
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:449)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:188)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:453)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Entity bean class: class ir.mehritco.megnatis.components.users.User, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:691)
    at ir.mehritco.megnatis.sito.repository.UserHibernate.getUser(UserHibernate.java:68)
    at ir.mehritco.megnatis.sito.ui.components.forms.login.UserManagedBean.selectedUser(UserManagedBean.java:79)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.glassfish.expressly.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.expressly.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.expressly.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:248)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:70)
    ... 38 more
]]

[2023-05-08T03:37:43.944423+03:30] [GF 7.0.3] [SEVERE] [] [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.context] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Entity bean class: class ir.mehritco.megnatis.components.users.User, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Entity bean class: class ir.mehritco.megnatis.components.users.User, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:691)
    at ir.mehritco.megnatis.sito.repository.UserHibernate.getUser(UserHibernate.java:68)
    at ir.mehritco.megnatis.sito.ui.components.forms.login.UserManagedBean.selectedUser(UserManagedBean.java:79)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.glassfish.expressly.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.expressly.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.expressly.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:248)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:70)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.faces.core.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxHandler.java:391)
    at jakarta.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:99)
    at jakarta.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:79)
    at jakarta.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:471)
    at jakarta.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:858)
    at jakarta.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1332)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:56)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:72)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:159)
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:691)
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:449)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:188)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:453)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
]]
```

as I mention about that after restart glassfish server I don't have this issue.

The Pom file and the persistence :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>ir.mehritco.megnatis.sito</groupId>
        <artifactId>Sito</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <name>Sito</name>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
    
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
            <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
            <junit.version>5.9.0</junit.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>9.1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.mvc</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.mvc-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20220924</version>
            </dependency>
    
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
                <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
                <version>4.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
    
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core-jakarta</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
    
    
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
        </dependencies>
    
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="jpa-connection-sito" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>ir.mehritco.megnatis.components.users.User</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mariadb://***.***.***.***:3306/db"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="******"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="******"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="jpa-connection-sito-local" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>ir.mehritco.megnatis.components.users.User</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3305/db"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*******"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

```
here are all Lib added into glassfish after deploy :

    file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/error_prone_annotations-2.10.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-jakarta-5.6.15.Final.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-jakarta-5.6.4.Final.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/istack-commons-runtime-4.0.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/istack-commons-runtime-4.1.1.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.13.4.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.13.4.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.activation-2.0.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.activation-api-2.0.1.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.mvc-api-2.0.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.persistence-api-3.0.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core-3.0.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core-4.0.2.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-runtime-3.0.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-runtime-4.0.2.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.36.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jna-5.12.1.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/jna-platform-5.12.1.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/json-20220924.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.20.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.20.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/mariadb-java-client-3.1.3.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/okhttp-4.9.1.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/okio-2.8.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/txw2-3.0.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/txw2-4.0.2.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Applications/Sito/target/Sito-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/waffle-jna-3.2.0.jar
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Softwear/glassfish703/glassfish/domains/sito/generated/ejb/Sito-1.0//
file:/D:/ProjectSpace/Softwear/glassfish703/glassfish/domains/sito/generated/Sito-1.0/
][delegate=true, context=/Sito-1.0, status=RUNNING, antiJARLocking=false, securityManager=false, packageDefinitionSecurityEnabled=false, repositories=RepositoryManager[WEB-INF/classes/], notFound.size=104, pathTimestamps.size=169, resourceEntryCache.size=129]]]
```

Comment: Hello balusc respect for your all helps in the stackoverflow , can I ask you what library exact you mean or right pom file look like?(in this project)

Comment: @BalusC have any tools for intllij that check these? or do it manually?I added to all and not work result are the same.